# Nodejs uploading my image from view to controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload

In my view, I selected an image. In my controller, I have a function called

`uploadImage: function (req, res){}`

I have this line `req.file ('photofile').upload (.....`

So my problem now is.. how do I pass this image from my view to my controller? So that I can read it from `req`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a route that is bound to your `uploadImage` function. If not, you can create it using `express`:

```
var app = require('express')();
app.post('/your/upload/route', uploadImage);
```

If you want to upload a file from your view, you have two choices:

- use a simple HTML `<form>` and a `<input type="file" />`. You must add in the `<form>` tag the following property: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`! Here you go:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photofile" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

- use an asynchronous call to `/your/upload/route` as a POST request with the file content in a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object. In this example I use jQuery (`$`) as dependency and I do an AJAX call, you can adapt if you want. But remember, be careful because this solution isn't supported by all/old browsers ([list here](http://caniuse.com/#search=FormData)):

```
<form onSubmit="upload()">
    <input id="image" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

```
function upload() {
    var inputFile = $('#image');
    if (inputFile.files[0]) { // Just checking if the user selected a file.
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('photofile', inputFile.files[0]); // Add the file in the form data.

        $.ajax({ // Call your route
            url: '/your/upload/route', // The route to call
            data: data, // The FormData
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data){
                console.log('Upload success!', data);
            },
            error: function (result, status, error){
                console.log('An error occurred.');
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('You didn\'t choose any image');
    }
}
```

Comment: Erm where am I supposed to place the require express code? In my controller?

Comment: I don't have the express plug in. How should I be writing my routes? I've tried the first option using the forms.. <form id="uploadForm" exctype="multipart/form-data" action="/postsManagement/uploadImage" method="post"> is this correct too? I did a print line in my uploadImage function in my controller but it's not printin so it wasn't called

Comment: Hi, thought you were using `express`, no problem. If you want to know what is `express` and how it works, you can follow [this documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) once you installed the package with the `npm install --save express` command.

Comment: Express is the only way to go about doing this? >.<

Comment: No, as I said in my post you can use a basic POST `<form>` and submit it to your controller.

Comment: I tried the form post method but my controller isn't called. Am I supposed to write something in routes in order for that to work?

Comment: I would like to know how your route is configured. If you can paste a part of your code using pastebin.com or something else because the code is hard to read in stackoverflow comments :/

Comment: I'm working in an offline environment so i'm unable to copy and paste the code. But if i rmb correctly it goes something like { "POST /postManager/uploadImage", controller: PostManagerController }.

Comment: I don't know this format, what are you using to define your route and controllers ? Vanilla Node.js ? A package ?